# Split vector into contiguous runs of equal values

Tags: r

I have a data table and one of the columns is a bunch of 0's and 1's, just like `vec` below.

```
vec = c(rep(1, times = 6), rep(0, times = 10), rep(1, times = 11), rep(0, times = 4))

> vec
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
```

What I want to do is to split the data everytime there's a change in that column from 0 to 1 or vice-versa. Here is what I have done so far:

```
b = c(vec[1],diff(vec))

rowby = numeric(0)
for (i in 2:(length(b))) {
  if (b[i] != 0) {
    rowby <- c(rowby, i-1)
  } 
}
splitted_data <- split(vec, cumsum(c(TRUE,(1:length(vec) %in% rowby)[-length(vec)])))
```

There must be some thing right under my nose I can't see. What is a correct way to do this? This works for the example above, but not generally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
 split(vec,cumsum(c(1, abs(diff(vec)))))
 #$`1`
 #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1

 #$`2`
 #[1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 #$`3`
 #[1] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

 #$`4`
 #[1] 0 0 0 0
```

Or use `rle`

```
 split(vec,inverse.rle(within.list(rle(vec), values <- seq_along(values))))
```

---

With current versions of `data.table`, `rleid` is one function which can be used for this job:

```
 library(data.table)#v1.9.5+
 split(vec,rleid(vec))
```